# Regex to find URLs, excluding emails

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing regex in javascript to grab the URLs in a string, excluding emails. I'm then wrapping them in an anchor tag. What I've done is finding all cases including email, which I don't want. Here is what I have so far:

```
var string = 'www.stinogle.com, http://stinogle.com, stinogle.com, not stinogle@gmail.com.',

replacePattern1 = /(\b(?:http|https):\/\/)?([-a-zA-Z0-9.]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,4})\b(?:\/[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)?/gi,

text1 = string.replace(replacePattern1, "<a href=\"$2\" target=\"_blank\">$2</a>");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/stinogle/DY5hQ/

How can I do this with regex?

Comment: If you do not have URLs that contain"`@`", then you have your answer. No regex required. Just use `contains()` or `indexOf()`.

Comment: @PM77-1 How would I used that in conjunction with the regex above? I still need to find the non-email URLs and wrap them in anchor tags.

Comment: Can you `split()` your string by space or by comma?

Comment: What about a workaround? https://eval.in/172803